# Practical use of order of rotational Symmetry.

Tags: geometry, applications, symmetry

Has anyone know what is the use of finding the order of the rotational symmetry of a figure? A student of mine ask that question from me. I search it but could not find any. Plz help.

https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/symmetry-rotational.html

Comment: Jordan Ellenberg's excellent book _How not to be wrong_ (see especially pp. 2-3) has a nice answer to "What is this [homework] good for?" It's too long to post here, but the gist is, "If you want to get good at something (mathematics, soccer, piano...) you have to practice. Even if you don't plan to become a professional mathematician, mathematical thinking allows you to see the world more deeply, to live life more fully." Ellenberg goes on (for several hundred highly engaging pages) to give concrete examples.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Are you talking about the group of symmetries of some figure, and then the *order of the symmetry* would be it's order as an element of that group?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang  Cool reference :)

Comment: @uniquesolution I'm asking, if a shape has a rotational symmetry and there is rotational symmetry order for that rite. Why we need to find the order? what is the use of it?

Comment: Sorry, Sara, I do not understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if my screw only has a two-folod rotational symmetry, I need a different screwdriver than if it has a four-fold or six-fold symmetry. So there are real-life applications.

In many branches of science, knowing the order of some rotation is an essential step in classifying something, and the above is some very every-day example for this kind of classification.